Styling on Android Checkbox Lost After Click
I'm trying to style some checkboxes (the box itself, not the label) to have a set color when checked vs unchecked.
To facilitate this, I created the following theme:
    <style name="checkBoxStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FF598392</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>

From there, I implemented the theme in my activity layout:
...

<CheckBox
    android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
    android:id="@+id/search_ingredients_checkbox"
    android:text="@string/search_ingredients" />
<CheckBox
    android:theme="@style/checkBoxStyle"
    android:id="@+id/search_directions_checkbox"
    android:text="@string/search_directions" />

...

So far, everything works as expected. However, once I try to click the checkbox in my emulator, the checkbox color is set to black, and the the uncheck box is also that same black.

I have not added any listeners to the checkboxes, so it's nothing I'm doing as far as I can tell.
I've attempted a clean/rebuild of the project, and a new emulator setup. Unfortunately, the behavior persists.
Is there anyone who knows how to stop this behavior, or if I'm supposed to style this a different way? The Layout manager says the Checkbox is from Material3, but using Widget.Material3.CompoundButton.CheckBox as the parent in the theme messes up the color and sizing of both the box and label.
Gradle: com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.3.2
targetSdk: 34

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'


Figured it out, finally found the right docs to help with this use case here.
The problem was not knowing that the "color" used by buttonTint can actually be a selector, in which you can specify the checked and unchecked states. For this I created a file called button_tint.xml like the linked documentation above.
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="@color/tertiary" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/tertiary"/>
</selector>

With that, you can import it into a style in your Theme file like so:
<style name="Widget.App.CheckBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="buttonTint">@color/button_tint</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

Then you can apply it to all checkboxes in your project by add the item in your main theme:
<item name="checkboxStyle">@style/Widget.App.CheckBox</item>

Or just specify the style when declaring it in your layout file
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/someTextbox"
    style="@style/Widget.App.CheckBox"
    ...

